# Validation with min option

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have mongoose schema with field validate option min:

```js
export const CartSchema = new Schema < ICartSchema > ({
    amount: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1,
        min: 1
    }
}, {
    versionKey: false
});
```

When I try update my document and set value <1, I didn't get some error and document get value <1

```js
switch (type) {
    case "inc": {
        update = {
            $inc: {
                amount: 1
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    case "dec": {
        update = {
            $inc: {
                amount: -1
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    default:
        throw Error("Bad request");
}
```

mongoose version ^6.0.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators-only-run-for-some-operations) says:

> One final detail worth noting: update validators only run on the following update operators:

> - `$set`
> - `$unset`
> - `$push` (>= 4.8.0)
> - `$addToSet` (>= 4.8.0)
> - `$pull` (>= 4.12.0)
> - `$pullAll` (>= 4.12.0)

Even the uses `$inc` as example where validators doesn't work:

> For instance, the below update will succeed, regardless of the value of number, because update validators ignore $inc.